# What kind of Bonferroni adjustment to apply

Tags: statistics, p-value, significance, model-comparison, bonferroni

I am currently working on sign predictability of certain non-linear models for various financial assets.

The following table shows the percentage of correct sign forecasts  for 5 financial asset generated using 9 different models where *, ** and *** indicate significance at 10%, 5% and 1% level, respectively, for two-tailed binomial tests with H0: p=0.5.

[image: This table]

Now, my question is, **should I or shouldn't I apply a Bonferroni adjustment?**

If so, **should I adjust for the number of models, number of assets or both?**

I am in doubt because the columns are highly correlated due to the fact that - if one model performs well on one asset, it tends to performs well on others as well.

Comment: What exactly is your problem and goal? Why do you have total rows and columns? What are your hypotheses? Why are you talking about performance of models if these are just hypotheses of proportions?

Comment: The marginal row totals demonstrate the strength of each model in terms of direction of change forecast, irrespective of financial instrument under consideration. Similarly, marginal column totals demonstrate the ability of all models to predict signs of a distinct financial asset. In both cases, if the sign prediction is correct more than 50% of the time, this provides suggestive evidence that the model performs better than one would expect in a random setting. To test for significance, I apply a binomial test. This test needs an adjustment, however, due to the multiple comparison problem.